# Indicating an empty array in a PHP switch

Tags: php, arrays

The code below displays a table row with one cell, featuring the words "Cultural Symbols," followed by a second, database-generated row (`$SymbolRow3`). How can I modify it so that the first (static) row doesn't display if there's no data in `$SymbolRow3`?

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3"><strong>Cultural Symbols</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php echo join ($SymbolRow3, ''); ?>
```

I apparently can't put $SymbolRow3[] inside a switch, so I tried this, without success:

```
switch($SymbolRow3)
{
 case '':
 case ' ':
 break;
 default:
 echo '<tr>
   <td colspan="3"><strong>Cultural Symbols</strong></td>
 </tr>';
 break;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) `if(!empty($SymbolRow3)) echo '<tr>'...etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will ensure $SymbolRow3 contains something before outputting the rows.

```
if ($SymbolRow3){
    echo '<tr><td colspan="3"><strong>Cultural Symbols</strong></td></tr>';        
    echo $SymbolRow3;
}
```

Comment: Weird. The other suggestions weren't really working, though they're good tricks to know. Your suggestion does work - with one tiny catch. If there are no values in $SymbolRow3, I get a minor "undefined variable" error. I can fix it by going to the top of the food chain and posting $SymbolRow3[] = ''. But when I do that, YOUR script doesn't work. If I can't figure it out, maybe I can ask a new question.

Comment: try removing the [], so it's $SymbolRow3='';

Comment: "Duh," as I slap my face. Thx. ;)

Answer (score 1):

you could check for rows in the variable instead of using a switch

```
<?php
    if (count($SymbolRow3) > 0) {
        echo '<tr>
            <td colspan="3"><strong>Cultural Symbols</strong></td>
        </tr>';
        echo join ($SymbolRow3, ''); ?>
    }
?>
```